# Autovacuum Triggered for transaction wraparound for a table even with increased autovacuum_freeze_max_age at table level

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, autovacuum

I am having postgresql RDS and Aurora instances. On version 12, having a hot table that approached 200M trx id. To prevent it from hitting autovacuum for trx wraparound, I set the table autovacuum_freeze_max_age to 600M as I could not perform restart to change this value autovacuum_freeze_max_age on instance level.

`alter table sample_table SET (autovacuum_freeze_max_age=6000000000);`

However, when the table reaches the trx id 200M, autovacuum trx wraparound for that table got triggered. Even I checked the table structure, the above autovacuum_freeze_max_age value is updated to 600M.

Now the question is

1. why this happened even with these changes ?
2. Need to check any other parameters ?

Any suggestions appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to set `toast.autovacuum_freeze_max_age`.

Answer (score 0):

Any ordinary vacuum launched on the table (auto or manual) will be promoted to a wraparound vacuum if vacuum_freeze_table_age is exceeded.  This is the main way freezing takes place.

Setting autovacuum_freeze_max_age mostly only matters if autovacuum is disabled (either explicitly, or effectively by setting bizarre values for other settings), or for insert-only tables (this one changes in v13).

Answer (score 0):

look vacuum_freeze_table_age parameter value in postgresql.conf file.